# Jenkins build failure - Android app

Tags: java, android, jenkins, automation, devops

I'm setting up Jenkins to work with our Android app.
I get the source code and try to build it.

The build fails with the following message :

```
10:43:35.419 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:43:35.419 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:43:35.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:43:35.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:43:35.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
10:43:35.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
10:43:35.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
10:43:35.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:43:35.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
10:43:35.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.

A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
```

Any idea for a solution ? could not find anything useful online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Java SDK Version 9 and installing Java SDK Version 8 fixed this for me.

I uninstalled the SDK on OS X using the instructions below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

Comment: Just discovered that a couple minutes ago ! that is correct, Thank you !

Comment: It's not a solution, it just hides the problem

Comment: Althogh not a fix, this is still useful information.